# Firebase Firestore: Insufficient permissions to write

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to write a document, but get

> Missing or insufficient permissions.

My rules looks like:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to write

```
const accountBalanceRef = db.collection('accountBalances').doc()
accountBalanceRef.set({
    type: s.type,
    accountName: s.accountName,
    startingBalance: s.startingBalance,
    endingBalance: s.endingBalance,
    statementYear: s.year,
    statementMonth: s.monthNumber,
    createdAt: now,
    uid: this.props.uid
})
```

Whats wrong? `this.props.uid` is my user ID

**RESOLVED**:

With @Bob Snyder's help, I resolved it with the following rule

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

I need to have different rules for read and write. I think its because for a read, I don't exactly have `request.resource.data.uid` set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a Firestore security rule, [resource.data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#resource_1) is the value of the document in the database.  Your rule does not allow creation of an `accountBalance` document because `resource.data` is null.

If you want your rule to require that the uid field in an `accountBalance` equals the uid of the authorized user, the rule should use `request.resource.data.uid`.

```
allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.uid;
```

The documentation for [request.resource](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#properties) explains:

> The [request] resource variable contains data and metadata about the document
>   being written. It is closely related to the `resource` variable, which
>   contains the current document at the requested path, as opposed to the
>   document being written.

Comment: so for this to work, i will need to provide the `uid` everytime i want to do a write?

Comment: Your post does not make clear what behavior you want the rules to enforce.  Can you explain more?  Maybe you need one rule for `create` and another for 'update' and 'read'.  There are [more request methods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#request_methods) than just `read` and `write`.

Comment: For some reason, it still does not work with missing permissions error. Is there some way to debug? The desired outcome should users can always write as long as the record has a uid that matches their uid. Users can only update their objects

Comment: No debug tools that I am aware of.  Firestore does not have a rule simulator like the RealTime DB.  Sounds like `this.props.uid` is not signed-in user's `uid`.  Try logging both just before you attempt the write.

Comment: Resolved with rule in the OP. The problem I think is for read, `request.resource.data.uid` is not set? So I need to use `resource` instead

Comment: That makes sense--I didn't think about how it would not be set for read.